# How to add assertion to sub sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a sampler for which retrieve embedded resources is enabled. This single sampler is generating 6 sub samples. I added size assertion and selected "sub-sample" radio box in "Apply to". During replay, all other 5 sub samples are getting failed due to failure of assertion. Please tell me if there is any way to validate specific sub sample only?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid JMeter's Size Assertion doesn't provide enough flexibility, you will need to consider switching to the [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) where you can implement whatever you want pass/fail criteria in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language.

Example code for your use case:

```
prev.getSubResults().each { subResult ->
    if (subResult.getSampleLabel().equals('generate_pdf-6')) {
        if (subResult.getBodySize() < 30000) {
            subResult.setSuccessful(false)
            subResult.setResponseMessage('Download size is less than 30 000 bytes')
            prev.setSuccessful(false)
            prev.setResponseMessage('Download size is less than 30 000 bytes')
        }
    }
}
```

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Just wonder what if I need to validate a text in sub sample instead of bytes size?

Comment: `subResult.getResponseDataAsString().contains('value you want to check')`. See [JavaDoc for SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class for all available functions and properties and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to learn more about other JMeter API shortcuts available for the JSR223 Test Elements

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting **Response Body** under Response size field to test and configure the "size to assert" section based on that specific sample.

Response size field to test options:

- Full Response - In the sampler you have "Size in bytes"
- Response Body - In sampler you have "Body Size in bytes"
- Response Headers - In sampler you have "Header Size in bytes"